# In SSMS, how do I change a SQL query window's tab name?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to know how to change the tab name of a SQL query window:

[image]

Instead of `SQLQuery8.sql…Registry(sa(51))`, I would like to have a custom caption.

If the query window has a very title, I can only open 3 windows at a time. I want to open more than 10 windows. So I need to change the query window's name to something very short, something like `Q1`, `Q2`, etc.

How can I change this?

Comment: Save query with your own name

Comment: no  no,,i want to change this query window name??

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/fixing-sql-server-management-studios-tab-text/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually rename tabs in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882651/manually-rename-tabs-in-ssms)

Comment: It is pathetic that in common "select/edit top 1000 rows" queries, one can't simply have the tab name automatically be the table name.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In SSMS, go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `Editor Tab and Status Bar`.

You can manage some options of *tab text*, as shown in the picture below.
(for example don't include db name, file name, login name and/or server name).

[image: SQL Server Options]

Comment: @user3252014 yes. And it's only applying when creating a new tab. If you set the 4 to false, you will only get `SqlQuery8.sql` for example.

Comment: is there any way to change this name?

Comment: @user3252014 You mean `SqlQuery<n>` to `q<n>`, for example ? Don't think so (well at least I donnow how to do this), without saving, but that's not what you're looking for, sadly.

Comment: you said if i set 4 to false it will show sqlquery8,sql,i want to know this name i can change or not? or this name coming defalultily..?

Comment: @user3252014 and my previous answer (comment) is about that. Donnow if (and if yes how) you can change this default.

Comment: @user3252014: There's no point in simply repeating your question over and over again. You got an answer. Please consider that what you want might simply be impossible beyond the answer(s) that you've already received.

Comment: Set the options to only show file name. Then each time you create a new query quickly save it to some c:\temp directory or similar with a useful name. This is what the man Brent Ozar does http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/fixing-sql-server-management-studios-tab-text/

Comment: Note: you have to reload (ie. save, close and open again) the tab to make changes live.

Comment: Can someone explain how n is calculated here after login in brackets? It looks like changing  without any pattern. login (n)?

Comment: I have always been troubled by this non-sense stuffs in the tab name.. glad those can be changed at least..

Answer (score 1):

My solution when I've got multiple tabs open is to save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then renaming it to the table name—or whatever it needs to be to make the query recognisable at a glance.
Go into *Tools* > *Options* > *Text Editor* > *Editor Tab and Status bar*, and set all tab text to **false** except for *Include file name* (set this to **True**).

Now, when I next execute the query, the Tab text presents the new filename.

Comment: Almost 9 years after the question has been asked and still no way to do this... Saving each file is just extra work and you end up with a bunch of files.

Comment: What OP is looking for is like set SqLPrompt like Oracle SQL plus. I did that when I was in Oracle. The tab did say something, but it has IP address. I don't know about others, but I tend to forget server name with IP. I want to label dev/test. This is not doable unless saving text file. MSFT is not going to do anything. it has been 9 years