# Show only table name in SSMS 2012 Tab for table (edit all rows)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

The tab name in SSMS 2012 is in the format : [SERVER_NAME.DATABASE_NAME - dbo.TABLE_NAME]
Is there is any way that i could show the tab like [dbo.TABLE_NAME] only, so more tabs would apear instead of only 4 tabs in case of oppening tabs with Edit Rows mode?

I have checked this [link](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/fixing-sql-server-management-studios-tab-text/) but it seems that it is not working on SSMS 2012

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SSMS, how do I change a SQL query window's tab name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653134/in-ssms-how-do-i-change-a-sql-query-windows-tab-name)

Comment: Related (but on a different SE site): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55307/display-table-names-in-titles-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: (Note that changing the tab name options does not affect already opened tabs. You have to close them first and perhaps even reconnect to the server / restart SSMS until the changes take effect.)

Comment: i checked this two links also i did restart SSMS after the change... but still no effect, the only two difference i think of is that the SSMS is 2012 or i am trying to accomplish this on table tabs not only query tabs

Comment: Perhaps you should say so in your question. You only said "SSMS 2012 tab", whatever that means. But SSMS 2012 definitely doesn't have less functionality in that respect than previous versions.

Comment: i did now, i think it is more descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found something that may solve the problem somehow. 
just pin some tabs, and you will have two rows of tabs which could give you space

[image]