# Is there any way to create a tab alias in SQL Server Management Studio 2016 without saving?

Tags: ssms

When I have over a dozen tabs open in SSMS, it can be hard to keep track of which tabs contain the queries that I am using.  I was wondering if there was a way for me to manually name the tabs something other than 'SQLQuery[X]'. I know that the tabs will be named if I save the query onto my system, but I was hoping for a more temporary solution that avoids saving.  Is this possible?  Thanks

Comment: I have been wanting that feature for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no options to set this ... except the below subtle alternatives

1. `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor (Editor Tab and Status Bar)`

[image]

2. Use the MDI window option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, review this thread on SO:
[Manually rename tabs in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882651/manually-rename-tabs-in-ssms) @KM. suggests that you might find the window menu more useful then tabs.

> @KM.> then don't use tabs, switch to window view:

```
  from the menu:
    tools - options
      in the dialog box, environment - general:
        click on the "MDI" environment radio button
```

> @KM.> I fought with the tabs and gave up, this works better for me. the tabs just show the first few characters, which ends up being the beginning of the database name, which was usless for me. You can use menu - "window" to see a list of your windows.

Then consider this: If you were going to go to the trouble of right clicking the tab, to rename it. Then why not go the next step and right click, select save-as and enter your name?

> How many ad-hoc scripts are you writing and executing on a daily basis that you don't think saving is a good idea? If you have that many open execution windows that you can't track them in the tabs, then perhaps you are spending too much time each day re-writing scripts? This time could be better spent by saving, organising and re-using scripts in the next session.

Saving regularly is not a bad thing, I have folders of many different working sets of queries, and yes sometimes end up with many open at the same time... By saving them I can go back to past scripts from previous sessions, or sometimes scripts get promoted to my common folder.

Saving also means I can restore a previous session after power down easily enough.

For added 'shits and giggles' my scripts folder is stored in onedrive so now I'm synchronised across workstations without any extra effort.