# how to rename sql server tabs

Tags: ssms

I used to be able to  rename the tabs in sql server in my old company. The sql server looks the same in my current company, but i'm not able to completely rename the tabs, and it gets confusing when many tabs are open.

(I'm able to add new names to the name that's already there. e.g. the tab is now called "SQLQuery20.sqlComputernameuser". And I'm able to rename it to "NewnameSQLQuery20.sqlComputernameuser". But I would like it to just be called "Newname" instead.)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  Because "SQL Server" is not an application with a UI at all - it is the database engine.  There are many desktop and web apps that you might be referring to, so please edit your question and provide the name of the actual application you're asking about.

Comment: I see ! I did mean SSMS. Thanks ! : )

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can sort of do this still, but with SSMS 2012 and later, you're limited to using the sql file name, db name, etc. and you can't just type in the name directly anymore.  The solution linked to below still should be helpful for you!

See this question I found titled [Manually Rename Tabs in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882651/manually-rename-tabs-in-ssms)

Good luck! Please mark this as the answer if it's sufficient for you :)

Comment: This helps just partially, because you are forced to save tabs to files. I would like to rename a tab I'm currently working on, but I don't intent to save every single tab I make. It would create another problem of filesystem maintainability, unnecessary clutter of useless scripts, hard to find useful file in pile of saved scripts. It would be nice to right click, rename and still see star `*` that this hadn't been saved.