# How to rename tabs in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I used to be able to rename tabs to make it really short in SSMS in my old company. The SSMS has really long tab names now, and I can only show 4 tabs at a time since the names are so long. It would only let me add names to it and not completely replace it. Like all the server name, computer names are on the tab names. Please help... Thanks !

Comment: Annoying, isn't it? Tools,options,text editor,editor tab and status bar - this allows you to hide server/db/user text and just have the filename.

Comment: Pro Tip: Always export and backup your preferred settings to be able to import in a new environment.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882651/manually-rename-tabs-in-ssms